# PowerShell extract each zip file to own folder

Tags: powershell, foreach, zip, extract

I would like to unzip some files each into their own folder with the same name as the zip file. I have been doing clunky things like this, but as this is PowerShell, there is usually a much smarter way to achieve things.

Are there some kind of one-or-two-liner ways that I can operate on each zip file in a folder and extract it into a subfolder of the same name as the zip (but without the extension)?

```
foreach ($i in $zipfiles) { 
    $src = $i.FullName
    $name = $i.Name
    $ext = $i.Extension
    $name_noext = ($name -split $ext)[0]
    $out = Split-Path $src
    $dst = Join-Path $out $name_noext
    $info += "`n`n$name`n==========`n"
    if (!(Test-Path $dst)) {
        New-Item -Type Directory $dst -EA Silent | Out-Null
        Expand-Archive -LiteralPath $src -DestinationPath $dst -EA Silent | Out-Null
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks quite good so if its working fine no need to look for alternative solutions. of course there are always alternative solutions available but if it's running fine no need for modifications. one thing you could use is split-path for getting rid of the extension

Comment: You can get `$name_noext` from `$i.BaseName`, but other than that, what's wrong with the current implementation? Why is it important why fewer lines of code?

Comment: I often find that I do things like the above in simplistic ways but then later on I see some smart object-oriented way that simplifies my clunky approaches - really it's about better ways / tricks of doing things with PowerShell that are smarter and generically useful when I'm doing operations like this on multiple files, as I'm very often doing things like the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do with a few less variables. When the `$zipfiles` collection contains FileInfo objects as it appears, most variables can be replaced by using the properties the objects already have.

Also, try to avoid concatenating to a variable with `+=` because that is both time and memory consuming.
Just capture the result of whatever you output in the loop in a variable.

Something like this:

```
# capture the stuff you want here as array
$info = foreach ($zip in $zipfiles) { 
    # output whatever you need to be collected in $info
    $zip.Name
    # construct the folderpath for the unzipped files
    $dst = Join-Path -Path $zip.DirectoryName -ChildPath $zip.BaseName
    if (!(Test-Path $dst -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -ItemType Directory $dst -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $null = Expand-Archive -LiteralPath $zip.FullName -DestinationPath $dst -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}

# now you can create a multiline string from the $info array
$result = $info -join "`r`n==========`r`n"
```

Comment: This is great, some really interesting points here, thanks. Is the use of `$null =` just to suppress output? Would this be identical to `| Out-Null` at the end of those lines, or is using `$null =` a better construct in PowerShell?

Comment: @YorSubs Yes, that is correct. Personally I like `$null =` better because by using that, we don't send anything through the pipeline and therefore it is a tiny bit faster than `| Out-Null` as well.